# How to invoke a oAuth protected Http end point from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I am attempting to invoke an HTTP endpoint protected by the oAuth protocol. I can generate the token and invoke the endpoint using curl. I see the choice to launch the one with basic authentication, but I do not see the ability to invoke a scripted endpoint that is secured by client credentials. I see that there is an oAuthCredentials plugin, however it appears to be more of a Jenkins login plugin. I am not using pipeline code, I am trying to configure as free style Jenkins job. My requirement is just to invoke a oAuth protected http endpoint.

Comment: Are you on a Jenkins Pipeline? If so can you share the relevant Pipeline code?

Comment: I am not one pipeline code, I am trying to configure as free style jenkins job. My requirement is just to invoke a oAuth protected http endpoint.